# Sometimes AlarmManager not trigger if I close my app, sometimes it does trigger. What is the problem with that?

Tags: java, android

I don't want to use services run in foreground because they uses resources. If I open my app later the alarm triggers. One more point, if I whitelist my app from battery optimization it works well. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some devices do not permit applications from running in the background, or from being started by `AlarmManager`. These applications need to be "whitelisted" or added to a list of apps permitted to do this. Different manufactureres handle this differently. If you are running your app on such a device, you will need to have the app (manually) added to the whitelist or list of protected apps, or list of background apps, or whatever.

Comment: Later I noticed that the notification get triggered but at later time not exact, as you said If I whitelist my app it triggers almost perfectly.